# @lazylist - Converts a Python Generator to a List without evaluating every element

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, generator, lazy

Inspired by a [blog](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/07/lazy-python-lists.html) I read, I made a LazyList class that can wrap an iterable (`list`, `generator` etc.) and turn it into a MutableSequence (like `list`). This is great for when you both need to  generate results lazily and cache them once generated.

In my use case, a library I'm using expects input as a list/mutable sequence, however it is expensive (and unnecessary) for me to calculate these values - since each one requires a git repo to be cloned, and so I want to pass a generator expression instead. Here's what I came up with...

First some imports and type definitions:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import functools
import itertools
from typing import Callable
from typing import cast
from typing import Generic
from typing import Iterable
from typing import Iterator
from typing import MutableSequence
from typing import Optional
from typing import overload
from typing import Protocol
from typing import Sized
from typing import SupportsIndex
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from typing import TypeVar

if TYPE_CHECKING:  # py 3.10 only
    from typing import ParamSpec

    P = ParamSpec("P")

U = TypeVar("U", covariant=True)

class IterableAndSized(Protocol[U], Sized, Iterable[U]): ...
```

[I don't really know why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70306916/6609896) `U` has to be covariant here, it just does...

Now this is the main class `LazyList[T]` where T reflects the type of whatever iterable comes in. The iterable can also be sized - i.e. have `__len__` defined - this allows `lst[-5]` to work without generating the whole list eagerly:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

# modified heavily from https://github.com/abarnert/lazylist/blob/master/lazylist.py
class LazyList(MutableSequence[T]):
    def __init__(self, iterable: Iterable[T] | IterableAndSized[T]):
        self._nonlazy: MutableSequence[T]
        self._lazy: Iterator[T]
        self._len = len(iterable) if isinstance(iterable, Sized) else None
        if isinstance(iterable, MutableSequence):
            self._nonlazy = iterable
            self._lazy = iter(())
        else:
            self._nonlazy = []
            self._lazy = iter(iterable)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        if self._len is None:
            self._delazify()
            return len(self._nonlazy)
        return self._len

    @overload
    def _normalise_index(self, index: slice) -> slice: ...
    @overload
    def _normalise_index(self, index: SupportsIndex) -> int: ...
    def _normalise_index(self, index: slice | SupportsIndex) -> slice | int:
        "Convert -ve to +ve index - may delazify the entire list en-route"
        if isinstance(index, slice):
            return slice(
                0 if not index.start else self._normalise_index(index.start),
                len(self) if not index.stop else self._normalise_index(index.stop),
                index.step or 1,
            )
        else:
            return len(self) + idx if (idx := int(index)) < 0 else idx

    def _delazify(
        self,
        normalised_index: Optional[slice | SupportsIndex] = None,
    ) -> None:
        if normalised_index is None:
            self._nonlazy.extend(self._lazy)  # hydrate whatever is left
        elif isinstance(normalised_index, slice):
            try:
                end_of_slice = range(
                    normalised_index.start,
                    normalised_index.stop,
                    normalised_index.step,
                )[-1]
            except IndexError:
                pass  # range returned an empty array, so no need to populate further
            else:
                self._delazify(end_of_slice)
        elif (remainder := int(normalised_index) - len(self._nonlazy) + 1) < 0:
            pass  # that bit of list is already hydrated
        else:
            self._nonlazy.extend(itertools.islice(self._lazy, remainder))

    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, unsafe_index: SupportsIndex) -> T: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, unsafe_index: slice) -> MutableSequence[T]: ...
    def __getitem__(
        self,
        unsafe_index: SupportsIndex | slice,
    ) -> T | MutableSequence[T]:
        normalised_index = self._normalise_index(unsafe_index)
        self._delazify(normalised_index)
        return self._nonlazy[normalised_index]

    def __delitem__(self, unsafe_index: SupportsIndex | slice) -> None:
        normalised_index = self._normalise_index(unsafe_index)
        self._delazify(normalised_index)
        del self._nonlazy[normalised_index]

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, unsafe_index: SupportsIndex, value: T) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, unsafe_index: slice, value: Iterable[T]) -> None: ...
    def __setitem__(
        self,
        unsafe_index: SupportsIndex | slice,
        value: T | Iterable[T],
    ) -> None:
        normalised_index = self._normalise_index(unsafe_index)
        self._delazify(normalised_index)
        if (
            not TYPE_CHECKING
        ):  # see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70247756/mypy-incompatible-types-error-when-one-overload-function-calls-another-in-setitem
            self._nonlazy[normalised_index] = value
        elif isinstance(normalised_index, slice):
            self._nonlazy[normalised_index] = cast(Iterable[T], value)
        else:
            self._nonlazy[normalised_index] = cast(T, value)

    def insert(self, unsafe_index: int, value: T) -> None:
        if unsafe_index:
            normalised_index = self._normalise_index(unsafe_index - 1)
            self._delazify(normalised_index)
        if self._len is not None:
            self._len += 1
        self._nonlazy.insert(normalised_index, value)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        yield from self._nonlazy
        for value in self._lazy:
            self._nonlazy.append(value)
            yield value

    def append(self, value: T) -> None:
        if self._len is not None:
            self._len += 1
        self._lazy = itertools.chain(self._lazy, (value,))

    def extend(self, values: Iterable[T] | IterableAndSized[T]) -> None:
        if self._len is not None:
            if isinstance(values, Sized):
                self._len += len(values)
            else:  # size is no longer known if we chain a random iterable
                self._len = None
        self._lazy = itertools.chain(self._lazy, values)

    def clear(self) -> None:
        self._len = 0
        self._nonlazy, self._lazy = [], iter(())

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "[{}]".format(
            ", ".join(itertools.chain(map(repr, self._nonlazy), ["..."])),
        )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"LazyList({self})"
```

Finally I wrote some decorators for generator functions so they can work with lazy lists. Since generators don't have a length, -ve indexing would require eagerly generating the whole list to find the end and then step back. However the @sized decorator lets you specify a `__len__` for the generator to make it work (see examples at the end). This is [all tested with the mypy latest branch](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=11ac995ba5b91c47748db628f78109fa) to support ParamSpec variables:

```
def lazylist(
    func: Callable[P, Iterable[T] | IterableAndSized[T]],
) -> Callable[P, LazyList[T]]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> LazyList[T]:
        return LazyList(func(*args, **kwargs))

    return inner


class GeneratorLen(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, gen: Iterator[T], length: int):
        self.gen = gen
        self.length = length

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.length

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return self.gen


def sized(
    length: int,
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, Iterator[T]]], Callable[P, IterableAndSized[T]]]:
    def outer(
        func: Callable[P, Iterator[T]],
    ) -> Callable[P, IterableAndSized[T]]:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> IterableAndSized[T]:
            return GeneratorLen(func(*args, **kwargs), length)

        return inner

    return outer
```

#### Examples

```
@lazylist
@sized(10)
def sized_generator() -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    for i in range(10):
        print(f"Sized generated {i}")
        yield i


@lazylist
def unsized_generator() -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    for i in range(10):
        print(f"Unsized generated {i}")
        yield i


s = sized_generator()
print(f"{s[-3]=}")  # only generates up to 7
print(f"{s[:5]=}")  # doesn't generate any more values since we already have the first 5

u = unsized_generator()
print(f"{u[-3]=}")  # generates entire list
print(f"{u[:5]=}")  # doesn't generate any more values
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVhfb9s2EH/XpyC0h0mtYjQoig3GMqQIirbY1gWoM2AwDIO1KFurTGoUlUTN@tmzIylSpCTLXottfkgk6nh/f7w7XtmIHaPPvy/542PG2R6t11ktak7Wa5TvS8YFwpQygUXOaBW0S1lNN4Kxwi7kgnC9oJiIpszp1jCIAgS/xe/Xr9ZXb15d/fT23etELb2kjX64wkWBPxREv70mlHAsGHde841@eYOrXUf5FsT23uy2X2ohP70nf9aEblqSX0tpBy702zVngm1Y@@ZTvs8/kbR9rEtpR/WWpuReLy2akvyGW0kbXAn9xG4JLxiGfXEQBAt0YQijcBHGwY27cBMmaMNuMc8xFRcLXhPY8w3K9mKOWJYFwabAVWVNfElTpVJklF7erJJWS0sEa/EczWYzy4gGhtHP@FPzc16JqOeY5QL2KO1TkkH4c5qL9TqqSJElKq6SeN6JWKzQXwOtOibyJ/fO1pTRAmTO0VBgj1KTmfCNfCcUPAd/I6NPjPIM5VVOK4GBpV1vPRIjUlQEvWOUWFaHNvS0c8wYmAJKmH0jRA5FFMWxpZCqTDNdro6ws2YHTqDAH22cYnT2I8qpmLvGdq7LK@WJMR1SAmLyrIli7yMnkAKo8rina0fVUlghWjEXvvL90hyITm3K@B4XeUUAaHCcDM7k8xxVRQ4RkNaoJw3lL2HkHVnrHsvOOR3/QDHA/ZCv@eK5P7xiFBQW6OyWIMHQU/inOKEztMcNMm5HYkcQoSLnBIFoAc9nnNWChIdgq1JQ66f5WMzUp8j7In/PJCPI41qNGbAD7dQhMQH2rXfI4mTAzQAj7nNl5SlMWTnC03wkJWIcnfsEU6epB9YYPUV5ei81i@T/@YWMjZYdx@gHcIVSEb450bcHwUs9CbImpOsWCqaELEcxsYIja9OOAoh/9JS/fJZT57M9dzNyLwhNoy4zxBLEuyaFjEnQ3Q7@At4kp4JkwnGWD5@@6HEkCd7MB@EB8WuWrbXRF4hjuh2Bmfz1hWgUJWPrrBxdJuWAcbw8O/ezJLnfkFIg5fVXnDM@1LmUdQ/8pJRtcUJSaGgQ2ZeiQZhz3IAPGCiBKIFPcFZLVtaF9GpWczie3Bc6QN9ILnVdFfuxiDjZY2kmN7jsmw@YGcm7gOlzhV1fuDFQAADQh1xA5tV5BICAC05w2hiQpKfWI4M129LNcp1TOvAlyJoRxydn/vWWCGC6t81FTSuckfXBlL2YzP9H2HWlZNh@TBcCh3EvGUwoDHlASezO/QKWRkQHh44JHKrxrOlKjYMDmBvAaLxStzFe9slXrv3A9NQ4GbNHMt1/ZR@QnGbcKRCtTodogm5xUUOPsuiMn8RrdRyvlqfTbY9wH0Vt9RWo7WxxenvTh/@PsW27C@/qOJG6hpEHxZRlX1kRj0uRd8DI8Vzr0ZNvAYeZLiwrG2zQHnLzKIygpIwB0/WotyGYqtwnhRXq1Xk8dbWYDK93S5GxPtQJSZKnF@h8/JI5a10yDGffd3DBhSi5Fyfn3tkJbnJSpEgNMzxBliCDJlXxBpe719iJworLUhbWHjA6aRqpVtOWXEd5OqRf60XnrqlL/mYH5d2r@FrtJHZc6TSlrYLVKXOCL7XAP7hanrnvH@rJWntlQ6U3xMN2TubTCrhoyahg0Cxy9JGyOypl3hGkvIGw7CNTAMToDKA/rfBmDyd72ShpfbwpCOYdVn2vuPKejR@MxJe9XCXdgMItHsI7EvA67zcQ4fLh8yqcZfKECb/zDxMUzv5gOY36tu1xCS1vyRNfqzhByxCqWbhy5iSeQnLTMY2y0M60HiTh5zgM1E@ykGJkK6w1lQPLuR0zLkF0chypq0CJ9ncZkfK71ujSTkNndxyXVSTfY2uLXCvB408w3wJenzz5eCefFGuH2cA6a5tkN9jdOqulbWWYUZ8ywE5Ro3aAOjno2xLqTeASeWa2YqcqSn@0t1WIg7/@st6hJ3XwcOqsym1QhztPytYuC6mWhkCl5qWuHV44l/bpOnHZrlbJ4EsPGCvHj3v8kWhJXW3w0dZj3zVVx8R0Bk5gbBRnc3Q98xEjVxzkjYgbnar0oDSKRYOVFpNjuHTWOoep1UAOvclsO0PBpTmzwaV26PmzuAskXMuMFsoCq9RS9jwyMao/rRmyPOeyNOtBBXDqzCu5vHhnobINtWzh6SH/HMa9DiC37456Uidogf4drW4046N6BZVsz/o6BIbNQ7U8e766gJ1Q3iDrNpZhhepSDjq@c2nnLwxtykhFvxWWHGHaoD3jpC1OIBPqryyLdsKA5ZRzR1CW80qgF0FQg2ojDuoE1o5ynV7OJNQlPV234PHxbw)

---

### Update (more context)

Here's how I'm actually using this class:

```
class InfoBasedPackageSource(BasePackageSource):
    def __init__(self, pkg_info: PackageInfoFactory) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._pkg_info = pkg_info
        self._root_version = Version.parse("0.0.0")
        self._root_dependencies: list[Dependency] = []

    @property
    def root_version(self) -> Comparable:
        return self._root_version

    def add_root_requirement(
        self,
        descriptor: PackageDescriptor,
        requirement: str | None,
    ) -> None:
        self._root_dependencies.append(Dependency(descriptor, requirement))

    def _versions_for(
        self,
        package: Hashable,
        constraint: MixologyConstraint | None = None,
    ) -> Sequence[Comparable]:
        if not isinstance(package, PackageDescriptor):
            raise TypeError(f"Invalid package {package!r} was supplied")
        if isinstance(package.reference, git.Repo):
            all_versions = git_repo_versions(package.reference)
            # filter options according to the constraint if provided
            matching_constraint: Iterable[RepoVersion]
            if constraint:
                filter_function = partial(matches_constraint, constraint)
                matching_constraint = filter(filter_function, all_versions)
            else:
                matching_constraint = all_versions
            # filter out valid version tags with invalid configs
            valid_versions = (
                repo_version
                for repo_version in matching_constraint
                if is_valid_viv_version(package, repo_version)
            )

            # TODO: if this proves a bottleneck, a lazy list could be returned,
            # The mixology backend uses len() as a heuristic to determine the order
            # of packages to resolve - therefore we would need to return an object
            # with its __len__ set to a constant to avoid generating the values in
            # the lazy list just for this heuristic
            # wait to see if it's a problem and if lying about __len__ breaks the solver

            versions = list(valid_versions)
            logger.debug(f"Versions for {package!r} = {len(versions)}")
            return versions
        else:
            # static repos only have one version (which should never be specified)
            # TODO this means we don't validate the config so the error may come later
            assert False, "versions for static packages should be validated here"
            return [None]

    def dependencies_for(
        self,
        package: Hashable,
        version: VersionType,
    ) -> MutableSequence[Dependency]:
        if package == self.root:
            return self._root_dependencies
        if not isinstance(package, PackageDescriptor):
            raise TypeError(f"Invalid package {package!r} was supplied")
        if isinstance(package.reference, git.Repo):
            assert version is not None, "only static packages can have no versions"
            tag = to_git_tag(package.reference, version.git_tagref)
            deps = LazyList(
                Dependency(descriptor, requirement)
                for descriptor, requirement in get_deps(self._pkg_info, tag)
            )
            return deps
        else:  # static package so reference is a path
            return LazyList(
                Dependency(descriptor, requirement)
                for descriptor, requirement in get_deps_static(
                    self._pkg_info,
                    package.reference,
                )
            )
    ...
```

Quick explanation:

- InfoBasedPackageSource is a PackageSource for a package manager
- `def _versions_for(): ...` converts a package identifier e.g. "numpy" into a list of versions that package has (based on metadata from my package hosting service, currently github)

  - `_versions_for` returns a simple list of versions because this is constrained by an O(1) lookup operation (and O(n) parsing of version tags into Version types, but this is a quick step - see comment in that function anyway)
- `def dependencies_for(): ...` converts a *package version* into a list of dependencies (other package identifiers + constraints on which versions are supported)

  - `dependencies_for()` **returns a LazyList**, this is for 2 reasons:

    1. Firstly, generating the list of dependencies is a slow \$O(n)\$ operation, cloning of each of a package's \$n\$ dependencies' repos. This cloning is necessary to generate each dependency's `PackageDescriptor` (unique identifier), because the name of the package is defined in a metadata file in its repo.By using a lazy list, this \$O(n)\$ step is reduced to \$O(m)\$ -  where \$m\$ is the number of dependencies the resolver actually has to check before it finds a package conflict, and \$m \le n\$ (sometimes not all dependencies of a package have to be known, if for example a conflict is found at an earlier stage, later dependencies are irrelevant as the candidate package can already be discarded)
    2. Secondly, looking up the dependencies for a package for the first time involves a slow \$O(1)\$ git_checkout step and file parsing. Sometimes the resolver eagerly requests dependencies for versions of packages that it later discards without using. The LazyList saves all the work here.

#### tl;dr

The usecase for a lazylist is where:

- Initialising the generator is slow so you want to postpone this (e.g. it involves checking out a commit in a git repo and parsing one of the files).
- Iterating over the generator is slow and you don't necessarily need to evaluate the whole thing/it's an infinite generator (e.g. generating the next value involves cloning a git repo + sometimes you can bail early and don't need to generate all values).
- Unlike `itertools.islice`, you want to cache the generated values, and access them using list slicing (mutable sequence protocol), for example if multiple packages have the same dependency, you don't want to generate the dependent package's dependencies twice.

---

#### Feedback

I'd love to hear anything, but some ideas:

- Is this a stupid idea
- Performance
- Bugs and edge cases
- Pythonicness
- Type Safety
- User Interface (I want this to be obvious to use if possible)

This code looks complicated but I'm actually a bit of a python beginner so anything would be good feedback. Made with python 3.10 and mypy >=0.93x for ParamSpec (you can experiment [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=11ac995ba5b91c47748db628f78109fa)), the [TIO link](https://tio.run/##xVhfb9s2EH/XpyC0h0mtYjQoig3GMqQIirbY1gWoM2AwDIO1KFurTGoUlUTN@tmzIylSpCTLXottfkgk6nh/f7w7XtmIHaPPvy/542PG2R6t11ktak7Wa5TvS8YFwpQygUXOaBW0S1lNN4Kxwi7kgnC9oJiIpszp1jCIAgS/xe/Xr9ZXb15d/fT23etELb2kjX64wkWBPxREv70mlHAsGHde841@eYOrXUf5FsT23uy2X2ohP70nf9aEblqSX0tpBy702zVngm1Y@@ZTvs8/kbR9rEtpR/WWpuReLy2akvyGW0kbXAn9xG4JLxiGfXEQBAt0YQijcBHGwY27cBMmaMNuMc8xFRcLXhPY8w3K9mKOWJYFwabAVWVNfElTpVJklF7erJJWS0sEa/EczWYzy4gGhtHP@FPzc16JqOeY5QL2KO1TkkH4c5qL9TqqSJElKq6SeN6JWKzQXwOtOibyJ/fO1pTRAmTO0VBgj1KTmfCNfCcUPAd/I6NPjPIM5VVOK4GBpV1vPRIjUlQEvWOUWFaHNvS0c8wYmAJKmH0jRA5FFMWxpZCqTDNdro6ws2YHTqDAH22cYnT2I8qpmLvGdq7LK@WJMR1SAmLyrIli7yMnkAKo8rina0fVUlghWjEXvvL90hyITm3K@B4XeUUAaHCcDM7k8xxVRQ4RkNaoJw3lL2HkHVnrHsvOOR3/QDHA/ZCv@eK5P7xiFBQW6OyWIMHQU/inOKEztMcNMm5HYkcQoSLnBIFoAc9nnNWChIdgq1JQ66f5WMzUp8j7In/PJCPI41qNGbAD7dQhMQH2rXfI4mTAzQAj7nNl5SlMWTnC03wkJWIcnfsEU6epB9YYPUV5ei81i@T/@YWMjZYdx@gHcIVSEb450bcHwUs9CbImpOsWCqaELEcxsYIja9OOAoh/9JS/fJZT57M9dzNyLwhNoy4zxBLEuyaFjEnQ3Q7@At4kp4JkwnGWD5@@6HEkCd7MB@EB8WuWrbXRF4hjuh2Bmfz1hWgUJWPrrBxdJuWAcbw8O/ezJLnfkFIg5fVXnDM@1LmUdQ/8pJRtcUJSaGgQ2ZeiQZhz3IAPGCiBKIFPcFZLVtaF9GpWczie3Bc6QN9ILnVdFfuxiDjZY2kmN7jsmw@YGcm7gOlzhV1fuDFQAADQh1xA5tV5BICAC05w2hiQpKfWI4M129LNcp1TOvAlyJoRxydn/vWWCGC6t81FTSuckfXBlL2YzP9H2HWlZNh@TBcCh3EvGUwoDHlASezO/QKWRkQHh44JHKrxrOlKjYMDmBvAaLxStzFe9slXrv3A9NQ4GbNHMt1/ZR@QnGbcKRCtTodogm5xUUOPsuiMn8RrdRyvlqfTbY9wH0Vt9RWo7WxxenvTh/@PsW27C@/qOJG6hpEHxZRlX1kRj0uRd8DI8Vzr0ZNvAYeZLiwrG2zQHnLzKIygpIwB0/WotyGYqtwnhRXq1Xk8dbWYDK93S5GxPtQJSZKnF@h8/JI5a10yDGffd3DBhSi5Fyfn3tkJbnJSpEgNMzxBliCDJlXxBpe719iJworLUhbWHjA6aRqpVtOWXEd5OqRf60XnrqlL/mYH5d2r@FrtJHZc6TSlrYLVKXOCL7XAP7hanrnvH@rJWntlQ6U3xMN2TubTCrhoyahg0Cxy9JGyOypl3hGkvIGw7CNTAMToDKA/rfBmDyd72ShpfbwpCOYdVn2vuPKejR@MxJe9XCXdgMItHsI7EvA67zcQ4fLh8yqcZfKECb/zDxMUzv5gOY36tu1xCS1vyRNfqzhByxCqWbhy5iSeQnLTMY2y0M60HiTh5zgM1E@ykGJkK6w1lQPLuR0zLkF0chypq0CJ9ncZkfK71ujSTkNndxyXVSTfY2uLXCvB408w3wJenzz5eCefFGuH2cA6a5tkN9jdOqulbWWYUZ8ywE5Ro3aAOjno2xLqTeASeWa2YqcqSn@0t1WIg7/@st6hJ3XwcOqsym1QhztPytYuC6mWhkCl5qWuHV44l/bpOnHZrlbJ4EsPGCvHj3v8kWhJXW3w0dZj3zVVx8R0Bk5gbBRnc3Q98xEjVxzkjYgbnar0oDSKRYOVFpNjuHTWOoep1UAOvclsO0PBpTmzwaV26PmzuAskXMuMFsoCq9RS9jwyMao/rRmyPOeyNOtBBXDqzCu5vHhnobINtWzh6SH/HMa9DiC37456Uidogf4drW4046N6BZVsz/o6BIbNQ7U8e766gJ1Q3iDrNpZhhepSDjq@c2nnLwxtykhFvxWWHGHaoD3jpC1OIBPqryyLdsKA5ZRzR1CW80qgF0FQg2ojDuoE1o5ynV7OJNQlPV234PHxbw) is for 3.8 and is functionally equivalent.

Comment: For something like `only generates up to 7`, what does your code do that `itertools.islice` does not?

Comment: @Reinderien indeed this is built on islice to generate a subset of values on demand. But unlike islice, this fulfills the mutable sequence protocol so can be indexed or sliced like a regular list and use negative indices to generate some distance from the end. Also this caches values in a way that's a bit simpler than using tee. For example, if `a` is a lazy list, then `a[5]` generates up to index 5, `a[7]` generates only 6 and 7 and reuses the previous 5 values. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, but.. I'd like to hear more about why this is used with your repo generation case to trust that it's justified.

Comment: @Reinderien Good point, let me give some more details: I'm creating a package manager like pip where a git repo represents a package, and the repo contains a metadata file that specifies the version number of the package, and a list of dependencies + their compatible versions. Where this lazylist comes in is I'm using a library 'Mixology' to do automatic dependency resolution. For each package it expects a list of versions, most recent first, and their dependencies. However because this data is in the metadata file, I need to traverse the git history to obtain it...

Comment: ...which is slow as it requires checking out a commit and parsing the metadata file to get the version number + dependencies. The resolver starts from the most recent version of a package then works back until it finds a version that works with all the other packages - this doesn't require eagerly fetching all version metadata (hence the lazy part). Additionally, if 2 packages have the same dependency then this list of versions is re-used, so I also want to cache any work that's already been done in generating the list. The mixology code expects versions as a list so that's the api I've chosen

Comment: @Reinderien Long time coming ;) but I've updated the question with a full example